# When OSGi ServiceTracker modifiedService() method is actually invoked by the Framework?

Tags: java, osgi

I'm using the OSGi service tracker and I have noticed that the method [ServiceTracker.modifiedService(...)](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/util/tracker/ServiceTracker.html#modifiedService(org.osgi.framework.ServiceReference,%20java.lang.Object)) is never called.

I have tried to register the service twice with different properties, unregister it, etc..., but that method is never invoked by the Framework.

Anyone knows under which circumstances the OSGi Framework consider a Service "modified"?

The way I have used the OSGi service tracker is pretty standard.

```
this.serviceTracker = new CustomServiceTracker<S>(context, clazz, null);
this.serviceTracker.open();
```

I have a class which extends the OSGi ServiceTracker and overrides the following methods:

- modifiedService()
- removedService()
- addingService()

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The modifiedService method is called when the properties of the service are modified.

Comment: Do you mean that when the same ServiceReference is modified? How could it be done? AFAIK the only way is to register the same service with different properties, but it didn't work

Comment: https://osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/ServiceRegistration.html#setProperties%28java.util.Dictionary%29

Comment: okay, so from the ServiceRegistration I can update the service properties and this shall trigger the modifiedService() callback. Thanks!